# Using two instances of module -> Articles - Category

Tags: module, extensions, module-params

Currently attempting to use two instances of the module Articles - Category. However, the results for both listings always end up the same. The problem maybe in the fact that I'm referencing the same category but with different ordering and filtering. For example, I have one list ordered by Hits (Trending) and the other by Published Date (Latest).

Has anyone else experienced this? It works okay when I use a different category, but I suspect that the database call or reference is not unique when having this instance.  Attached are the screenshots for each module: [image: Latest Module]    [image: Trending Module]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [getStoreId](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/components/com_content/models/articles.php#L141) method in articles model, there is not ordering.

So this means that [getItems](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/legacy/model/list.php#L175) method thinks that these results are already in cache and returns it.

You alternative would be to change something that is in `getStoreId` and then it woulde treat models with different results.

For example make two different authors, who won't have any articles and mark them to different modules (one to latest, another to trending). Exclude these authors articles, and it should work like two different modules.

This is something that Joomla! community should work with. Can you [create issue](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues) for it?